# Let $(X,\mathscr U)$ be a uniform space. Then why does $\mathcal N_x=\{U[x]\ |\ U\in\mathscr U\}$ form a neighborhood base for $x\in X$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, uniform-spaces

Let $(X,\mathscr U)$ be a uniform space, i.e. $X$ is a set and $\mathscr U\subset 2^{X\times X}$ is a filter such that

1. $\Delta\subset U$ for all $U\in\mathscr U$
2. $U\circ V,U^{-1}\in\mathscr U$ for all $U,V\in\mathscr U$
3. For all $U\in\mathscr U$, there exists some $V\in\mathscr U$ such that $V\circ V\subset U$

where we define $$U^{-1}=\{(y,x)\ |\ (x,y)\in U\}$$ and $$U\circ V = \{(x,z)\ |\ (x,y)\in U,(y,z)\in V\hbox{ for some }y\in X\}.$$ Furthermore we define $$U[x]=\{ y\in X\ |\ (x,y)\in X\}.$$

Meanwhile, for any set $X$ and family of filters $(\mathcal N_x)_{x\in X}$ in $X$, we say that $(\mathcal N_x)_{x\in X}$ forms a *neighborhood filter base* if

1. $x\in N$ for all $N\in\mathcal N_x$
2. For all $N\in\mathcal N_x$, there exists some $M\subset N$, $M\in\mathcal N_x$ such that $y\in M$ implies that $M\in\mathcal N_y$.

A neighborhood filter base thus defines a topology $\tau$ on $X$. Note that we still have a topology $\tau$ on $X$ if we remove condition 2, but in that case, $\mathcal N_x$ might not be the neighborhood filter associated with $\tau$ at $x$.

Now, if we set $\mathcal N_x=\{U[x]\ |\ U\in\mathscr U\}$ for all $x\in X$, then it is clear that $\mathcal N_x$ is a filter satisfying condition 1, but I have yet to succeed in proving condition 2. I suspect I must use conditions 2 and 3 for the definition of a uniform space, but I don't see how.

Comment: Have you seen [my recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2392444/4280)? It's about exactly the same thing. I duplicate some of your definitions but I do think it addresses your question.

Comment: $\mathcal{N}_x$ is not a filter, it generates one. i.e. it's a filter base. Wikipedia made the same mistake. The generated filter is the one that equals the neighbourhood filter of the uniform topology exactly and to see that I use the last axioms (see the lemma lower down in my linked proof).